# How can I reduce the time that MPAndroidChart spend to show data?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have an application in which I have a `BarChart` and a `CombinedChart` but they spend 1-1.5 seconds until they show the chart with the data.

I retrieve data from a database with Volley doing a request to get the data but I would like that the time that both charts spend to show the data will be reduced as much as possible.

I guess that it could be by the form of import that library to the project:

```
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
```

but I could not find any other way to import that library or if it is the properly way to do this. Maybe it can be related by the fact that I am using Volley for this purpose.

What can I do to reduce the amount of time that both charts spend to show the data? Can it be something related with the form that I am importing it?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, the import has nothing to do with the loading time. Imports occur at compilation time. Have you checked that this 1-1.5 second is not caused by the volley request to the database instead of the MPAndroidChart library ?

Comment: @FlyingPumba If I do the request on Postman (for example) it spend less than 1 second, it is why I thought that it was something related with `MPAndroidChart`.

Comment: I use MPAndroidChart too togheter with a database, and i have similiar effect. This is because it takes some time to get the data from the database then it is processed. I just show a progress bar till my presenter passes me the data. Maybe try a different database that is proven to be faster. You can test greendao or realm for comparison

Comment: @Tazz And is it impossible to reduce the time instead of show a progress bar?

Answer (score 3):

The delay you are experiencing  has nothing to do the way you are importing the libraries since that is done in **compile** time and not **runtime**.

If you are requesting data from a **local** database that's just the time it takes to fetch the data. If you are looking for speed I would recommend you to use [Realm](http://realm.io/) which is the fastest read "database" for android right now.

As a bonus the PhilJay has integrated his `MPAAndroidChar` library directly with this,

you can find it here: [MPAAndroidChart-Realm](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart-Realm)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I will try it as fast I could and I will accept the answer if it finally makes it goes faster.

Comment: No problem, Ill wait for your feedback, gl!